# How to change colors in a video file using command line?

Tags: command-line, video-editing

If I want to change a given color to a desired color in an image, I can call `imagemagick` via the following command

`convert input.png -fill <desired_color> -fuzz 10% -opaque <original_color> output.png`

This replaces the `original_color` (with 10% fuzz) with the `desired_color` (which can be passed very precisely via their RGB values).

> Is there a command line tool which can do this for a video file?

Comment: Questions seeking recommendations for tools are off-topic here. I'm not sure about [su]  so check their help about on-topic questions. Good luck.

Comment: Do the same command in a loop over each file in the video. Or perhaps look into ffmpeg. Perhaps it can do that.